# Erro em converter JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Erro ou Bug? Bom eu estou com um erro aparecendo no console do eclipse, na tela de cadastro o formulário grava perfeitamente, tudo ok, porem o console aponta:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Selecione"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.bb.uds.rotinas.controller.converter.PessoaConverter.getAsObject(PessoaConverter.java:18)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:171)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectOneValue(MenuRenderer.java:202)
```

Meu converter:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "pessoaConverter", forClass = Pessoa.class)
public class PessoaConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String id) {
        try {
            PessoaServices pessoaServices = new PessoaServices();
            return pessoaServices.obterEntidade(Long.valueOf(id));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object pessoa) {
        if (pessoa.toString().equals("-1")) {
            return null;
        }
        return ((Pessoa) pessoa).getId().toString();
    }

}
```

XHTML em que uso o *converter*:

```xml
<!-- RESPONSAVEL -->
<h:outputLabel for="responsavel" value="Responsável"
    styleClass="panelGridGerenciar" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="responsavel"
    value="#{rotinasBean.rotina.pessoaResponsavel}" required="true"
    requiredMessage="Selecione um responsável"
    converter="pessoaConverter">
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{rotinasBean.changeSubstituto}"
        update="substituto" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue="-1" />
    <f:selectItems var="_responsavel"
        value="#{rotinasBean.selectResponsaveis}"
        itemValue="#{_responsavel}" itemLabel="#{_responsavel.nome}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

O console aponta essa linha do erro.

```
return pessoaServices.obterEntidade(Long.valueOf(id));
```

Não sei se é realmente um erro ou um bug, desde já agradeço.

Comment: Você já debugou para ver os valores que são passados para as variáveis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu método `getAsObject` esta pegando a *string* **id**, que no caso tem o valor "Selecione" e está tentando dar um `Long.valueof("Selecione")` isso causa uma `Exception`. Se não quiser que aconteça a *exception* teste se o valor **id** é igual ao "Selecione" e trate isso como desejar, desde que o retorno seja `null`.

Comment: Beleza, valeu, realmente foi só fazer se o id == "selecione" e o erro no console não aparece mais. Valeu.

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver usando esse converter em um selectOneMenu, segue um exemplo de código:

```
<p:selectOneMenu  value="#{bean.lista}" converter="pessoaConverter">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue="#{null}"/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{listapessoas}" var="p" itemValue="#{p}" itemLabel="#{p.nome}"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Rafael e em um selectOneMenu mesmo, porem postei o meu ta igual ao seu exemplo e continua com esse erro.

Comment: Eu retiraria esse itemValue="-1" e deixaria null. Então o problema está no seu método getAsObject. No showcase do primefaces tem um exemplo de converter, eu fiz o meu baseado nele.